# panda scatter plot group color error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, colors

I have troubles to visualize my data properly in a panda scatter plot. Here is my code for the plot of "Aprop" (proportion of ingredient A in Feed) vs. Days. The group "Feed" is composed of 3 Feeds (1,2,3). Below you can see the result on the graph: all is green while the legend represents well the three colors. Can you help me to improve the code so the 3 colors appear on the graph?

```
groups = df.groupby('Feed') 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.Day, group.Aprop,
            marker='o', linestyle='', ms=3,
            label=name
            )
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: you can see the result on the graph : all is green while the legend represents well the three colors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary with colors and explicitly state which color to use for which group. For example:

```
color_dict = {1: 'r', 2:'b', 3: 'g'}
```

And adding the colors when plotting:

```
ax.plot(group.Day, group.Aprop,
        marker='o', linestyle='', ms=3,
        label=name, color=color_dict[name]
)
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives the same result. Maybe it is coming from my dataset.. should I do anything special on it so all data are plotted ? I have many individuals but it seems that not all of them are plotted. This might be the core problem...

Comment: ok, now both ways are working, it was a problem in my dataset !